# Probability With replacement

Tags: probability

A bag contains blue, red and white discs. In an experiment, 24 students in a class take turns to remove a disc from the bag, record its colour and replace it. This is repeated 10 times. At the end of the experiment the relative frequencies are:

Red: 118/240, blue: 83/240, white: 39/240

Anne suggests that there are 10 discs in the bag. Is this a reasonable suggestion?

Based on the information, how many discs of each colour do you think are in the bag?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I agree with John Chessant in the sense of the ratio of the various coloured discs, i.e. R:B:W = 3:2:1.
As to whether Anne's suggestion is "reasonable" or not, there  is a somewhat subjective element to this question.
I'm inclined to think that Anne must of had some prompting factor to suggest 10, she may have gave such a number because she could clutch all or most of the discs in the one hand thereby giving her a fair guesstament as to the number of discs.
 A statistician would deem it blatantly unreasonable, Anne's mother would deem it highly reasonable. I waver somewhere in between, after all it is not outside the realm of possibilities that the results can occur with the ratios of 5:3:2 however unlikely. But personally believing the ratio is most likely 3:2:1 with the actual numbers being 6,4,2, for Red, Blue and White respectively, then Anne's guesstament is out by only 2, if this is the case I still hold the same view regarding her suggestion i.e. Not unreasonable ( call me a softie).
In light of what I have said in the above I give my answer to the second question as----
Red=6
Blue=4
White=2

Answer (score 0):

I think that $10$ discs is not a reasonable suggestion. It is most likely to be a multiple of $6$. In that case, there would be $3n$ red discs, $2n$ blue discs, and $n$ white discs, for a total of $6n$ discs.

To see why, notice that since $240$ discs were recorded, the numerators give the number of times each disc was chosen (i.e., $118$ red, $83$ blue, and $39$ white). Notice that these are about a $3:2:1$ ratio! (One way to see this is to estimate $118\to 120$, $83\to80$, and $39\to40$.)

So the number of red discs is three times the number of white discs, and the number of blue discs is two times the number of white discs.

(**Edit:** Of course, it is possible that, given $10$ discs, the recorded numbers of discs would still be as above, but it is *extremely* unlikely.)

Comment: We're working with probability. It doesn't HAVE to be a multiple of 6, the results merely suggest it should.

A better explanation for why 10 discs is unlikely would be that if we assume 10 discs, we expect about a multiple of 24 sightings for each color, but both blue and white strongly suggest that's not the case.

Based on Anne's suggestion, I'd assume the total number of discs is 12, since she reached in and presumably guessed 10 based on how many discs she felt (not doing the math).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is most likely a multiple of $6$, and most likely $12$ discs. Maybe I should have clarified.

Comment: I think there are $8888$ discs in the bag, since it is quite heavy, but feels like a lucky bag. The results are absolutely consistent with that.

Comment: And you would be right. There is nothing to say that there can't be $8888$ discs in the bag.